# Difference between Turing machine and Universal Turing machine

Tags: turing-machines

I've read what a Turing machine and a UTM are, but I don't get the difference. What can a UTM do which a normal Turing machine can not?

Answer (score 15):

A universal Turing machine is just a Turing machine whose programming simulates other Turing machines.  That is, the input to the UTM is a description of a Turing machine $T$ and an input for $T$, and the UTM simulates $T$ on that input.

It's universal in the sense that, for any problem that can be solved by Turing machines, you could either use a Turing machine that directly solves that problem, or you could use a UTM and give it the description of a TM that directly solves the problem.

If you like, a UTM is an interpreter for (all) Turing machines.

Comment: It is also (one of) the first description(s) of a stored-program computer.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Good point. Was it thought of in those terms in the 1930s?

Comment: I don't think so. After all, it wasn't even thought of as a computer at all. Or rather, it was thought of as what was at that time called a computer, namely a human who computes logarithm tables etc. by hand. That's how Turing came up with his model: a pen, a piece of paper, a (limited) vocabulary, a (limited) memory, and a (limited) set of rules.

Answer (score 4):

A UTM can run any Turing machine on some input.

A Turing machine can be compared to a program. It takes some input and generates some output.

A UTM can be compared to a computer. It can take any program and run it with some input and generates some output.

The UTM is a Turing machine in itself, so the interesting idea here is that any Turing machine can be encoded as input understood by another Turing machine.

Comment: I think you have to be careful with this analogy. A Turing machine feels more like a special-purpose computer, to me: it's a "physical" device. But I suppose that part of the point is that these devices can be described as something like programs.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, by "special-purpose computer" do you mean a fixed-program computer? Would it be correct to say that the difference between a Turing machine and the UTM is analogous to the difference between a fixed-program computer and a stored-program computer?

Answer (score 2):

Every TM does just *one* task. It sums two input numbers, or it scans the input for some symbol, or it looks for a counterexample of Goldbach's conjecture ...

... or it (let us call it TM#1, since we will have a 2nd one shortly) gets two parts of input, where the first describes a TM, TM#2 (think of a (fixed) TM as a finite number of states and transitions and stuff like head directions) and next to the description of TM#2 a description of input to TM#2.

So TM#1 receives the pair ("TM#2" "input#2") as its input#1. And then TM#1 runs on this input#1 and behaves (to the outside, after termination!) as if it was TM#2 working on input#2. In case TM#2 would not halt, TM#1 won't do either.

Such a TM#1 is called a UTM, since it can behave like/fake/simulate any other TM you give it as TM#2. Think of a virtual machine (TM#1), a simulated program (TM#2), and an input to the simulation (input#2). The VM takes longer, but the results are the same.

Even TM#2 = TM#1 is possible ... then input#2 = ("TM#3" "input#3") and TM#1 is a UTM and now simulates another UTM (TM#2) which in turn meta-behaves as TM#3 on input#3, in symbols:

TM#3(input#3) 
= TM#2("TM#3 input#3") *since* we took TM#2 to also be a UTM
= TM#1("TM#2  'TM#3 input#3'")

Again: Behaviour is in terms of eventual final output, if and when halting, certainly *not* in terms of tape contents at any time, number of time steps etc., simulation takes (much) more time than doing it directly.